# Browser send back to tomcat "likely valid" JSESSIONID but tomcat recreate session and response to browser a renewed JESSIONID

Tags: java, session, tomcat7, jsessionid

In production environment - tomcat_7_0_53 behind Apache/mod_jk - our customers report problems caused by random lost session issues.

We have investigated enabling AccessLogValve and to exclude bad session handling in request processing, like programmatically invoking of session.invalidate or session.setMaxTimeInterval etc.., we have catched and logged HttpSessionEvent via HttpSessionListener interface implementation.

```
####################################################################################
##### Logging by AccessLogValve
##### At first access time tomcat sent cookie: JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340;
82.112.204.155 - - [03/Mar/2016:08:27:03 +0100] "GET /rdsv5i/servlet/custom-logon/clienti-asp HTTP/1.1" Cookie="__utma=31431036.270103424.1433757878.1456913762.1456990022.212; __utmz=31431036.1433757878.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=31431036.1.10.1456990022; __utmt=1; __utmc=31431036; CustomLogonServlet.company=IAP; user=caruso; rds_home_page_logon=%2Frdsv5i%2Fservlet%2Fcustom-logon%2Fclienti-asp%3F1456913769327" Set-Cookie="JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340; Path=/rdsv5i; Secure"

##### User work without problems for 10 minutes:
82.112.204.155 - - [03/Mar/2016:08:37:58 +0100] "POST /rdsv5i/spoolviewer/spoolavailable.jsp HTTP/1.1" Cookie="AlreadyConnectedGUID=f34dc1bb-a117-4405-a40d-289c73e07de9; JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340; __utma=31431036.270103424.1433757878.1456913762.1456990022.212; __utmz=31431036.1433757878.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=31431036.1.10.1456990022; __utmc=31431036; CustomLogonServlet.company=IAP; user=caruso; rds_home_page_logon=%2Frdsv5i%2Fservlet%2Fcustom-logon%2Fclienti-asp%3F1456990031203" Set-Cookie="-"

#### Suddenly Tomcat send renewed JSESSIONID=28C983BAE315B709093B357C0DE7810D; ignoring browser sent back cookie: JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340;
82.112.204.155 - - [03/Mar/2016:08:38:06 +0100] "POST /rdsv5i/spoolviewer/spoolavailable.jsp HTTP/1.1" Cookie="AlreadyConnectedGUID=f34dc1bb-a117-4405-a40d-289c73e07de9; JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340; __utma=31431036.270103424.1433757878.1456913762.1456990022.212; __utmz=31431036.1433757878.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=31431036.1.10.1456990022; __utmc=31431036; CustomLogonServlet.company=IAP; user=caruso; rds_home_page_logon=%2Frdsv5i%2Fservlet%2Fcustom-logon%2Fclienti-asp%3F1456990031203" Set-Cookie="JSESSIONID=28C983BAE315B709093B357C0DE7810D; Path=/rdsv5i; Secure"
```

and session lost issues...

```
#### Logging by my HttpSessionListener
##### At first access time tomcat sent cookie: JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340;
03-Mar-2016 08:27:03.437 INFO [ajp-apr-8109-exec-5] com.rds_software.RdsUtil.http.HttpSessionEventsLogger.sessionCreated id="ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340"

#### Suddenly Tomcat send renewed JSESSIONID=28C983BAE315B709093B357C0DE7810D;
03-Mar-2016 08:38:06.358 INFO [ajp-apr-8109-exec-6] com.rds_software.RdsUtil.http.HttpSessionEventsLogger.sessionCreated id="28C983BAE315B709093B357C0DE7810D"

#### Here destroy first access time JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340
03-Mar-2016 09:08:43.365 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] com.rds_software.RdsUtil.http.HttpSessionEventsLogger.sessionDestroyed id="ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340" lastAccessedTime="08:37" maxInactiveTimeInterval="1800" stackTrace="Stacktrace: 
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:806)
  org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.isValid(StandardSession.java:656)
  org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.processExpires(ManagerBase.java:532)
  org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.backgroundProcess(ManagerBase.java:517)
  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1352)
  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
"
####################################################################################
```

My question is:
How is possible tomcat create a new session at 08:38:06 when browser sent back JSESSIONID=ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340 and ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340 have been destroyed at 9:08:46?

At 08:38:06 Session ADDBC908E913C159A330C746ABFE2340 not was valid?

I worked heavy for a week to code a test case to reproduce this strange behaviour but unsuccesfully.

Increasing org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter loglevel, it seems that tomcat in some circumstances, is not able to recognize JSESSIONID sent from browser.

```
#AccessLogValve say:
93.145.128.242 - - [08/Mar/2016:10:16:35 +0100] "GET /uri Cookie="JSESSIONID=CE848CE8D53223658BD8D69D5CB667D4" Set-Cookie="JSESSIONID=0D954B6C1223E63C54DB8BDA265A7B83; Path=/rdsv5i; Secure"

#CoyoteAdapter say:
08-Mar-2016 10:16:35.864 FINE [ajp-apr-8109-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [uriBC] has value [/rdsv5i/rds-its/xmlv5i/js/customers/righi.js]
08-Mar-2016 10:16:35.864 FINE [ajp-apr-8109-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [semicolon] has value [-1]
08-Mar-2016 10:16:35.864 FINE [ajp-apr-8109-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parsePathParameters The variable [enc] has value [ISO-8859-1]
```

In normal circumstances I should see also:

```
08-Mar-2016 10:16:35.864 FINE [ajp-apr-8109-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parseSessionCookiesId  Requested cookie session id is CE848CE8D53223658BD8D69D5CB667D4
```

I suppose cookie parsing not handled properly, I will try to reproduce case activating RequestDumpValve.

Comment: How is your server structure? You have 1 http server with mod_jk and 1 tomcat?

Comment: @sgpalit The problem occurs both /uri1/* (load_balanced) and /uri2/* (single_instance). I have no evidence for configuration issues. But I have news, increasing CoyoteAdapter logging it seems tomcat in some circumstances, is not able to recognize JSESSIONID sent from browser

Comment: do you have session descripter in your web.xml for path /rdsv5i, is this path your application path in production also?

Comment: @sgpalit No session descriptor for context /rdsv5i which is the application path in production. In the logs you can see /uri but only for clearness. At this point I suppose it could be caused by a courious implementation of our old legacy software. I discovered in some session bean the reference of servlet request. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try proxy instead of mod_jk in your single instance environment? You should add something like below to your httpd.conf. I had same issue while i was working with mod_jk and spring security, now I am using proxy and have no problems. You should change httpServer and tomcatServer definitions.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName httpServer

   ProxyRequests Off
   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Proxy>

   ProxyPass /  http://tomcatServer:8080/rdsv5i
   ProxyPassReverse / http://tomcatServer:8080/rdsv5i

   <Location />
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Now I'm working to clean any HttpServletRequest reference by sessions bean. If not conclusive I will follow your suggestion. Thank you